# Receiving runtime error when using Tasks API

Tags: task

i've been running this small code successfully once a month for quite awhile. last run was just a few weeks ago in mid-july 2020. was just running for august, and i'm getting following error and could use some help figuring out what's happening. i made sure tasks api is still on, and tried running with new apps script runtime enabled and disabled. i've searched to see if something was changed or deprecated and didn't find anything but maybe i missed it ? can you help ?

code:

```
/**
 * Lists task items for a provided tasklist ID.
 * @param  {string} taskListId The tasklist ID.
 */

/* function listTasks(taskListId) { */

function listTasks() {

  var optionalArgs = {

    maxResults: 1000,

    showCompleted: true,

    showHidden: true

  };

  var response = Tasks.Tasklists.list(optionalArgs);

  var tasks = Tasks.Tasks.list("insert task list doc ID here", optionalArgs) ;

  var SPREADSHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var rngStartReport = SPREADSHEET.getRange('A1');

  var k = 1;

  if (tasks.items) {

    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.items.length; i++) {

      var task = tasks.items[i];

      rngStartReport.offset(k, 0).setValue(task.title);

      rngStartReport.offset(k, 1).setValue(task.status); 

      rngStartReport.offset(k, 2).setValue(task.due);

      rngStartReport.offset(k, 3).setValue(task.completed);

      k++;

      Logger.log('Task with title "%s" and ID "%s" was found.',
                 task.title, task.id);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No tasks found.');
  }

}
```

error message when running... i believe it is failing on this line of code: "var tasks = Tasks.Tasks.list("insert task list doc ID here", optionalArgs)"

*HttpResponseException: Response Code: 404. Message:     Error 404 (Not Found)!!1  *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//w.... (line 13, file "Code")*

Answer (score 0):

well... nevermind.

i just tried running it again and it successfully executed. no errors and i received the results.